# ¿Cómo duplicar un artículo en la cesta en una nueva fila al añadir un color diferente u talla?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

En el detalle del producto, tengo un formulario en el que se selecciona el color del producto y el tamaño y la cantidad del producto.

En la pagina de **detalle.php**

Tengo el siguiente código de seleccionar color del producto:

```
<?php
$sqlcolors = "SELECT * FROM colors WHERE product_id='$id'";
$querycolors = mysqli_query($kcon, $sqlcolors);
while($rowcolors =  mysqli_fetch_array($querycolors)){
$id = $rowcolors['id'];
$colors = $rowcolors['colors'];
$background = $rowcolors['background'];
echo'<input id="id-'.$id.'" type="radio" name="colors" class="selector-colors" value="'.$colors.'" />
<label for="id-'.$id.'" title="'.$colors.'" id="colors" style="background:'.$background.';"></label>';
}
?>
```

código de seleccionar la talla del producto:

```
<select name="size" id="size">
<?php
$sqlsize = "SELECT * FROM size WHERE product_id='$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($kcon, $sqlsize);
while($rowsize =  mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$size = $rowsize['size'];
echo'                                                                                                           <option value="'.$size.'">'.$size.'</option>';
}
?>                                                                                                                                                                                                                      </select>
```

Cantidad añadir cesta de la compra.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="quantity" name="qty" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float" value="1">
<a id="min">-</a>
<a id="plus">+</a>
```

Cuando selecciono el color y la talla de un producto se añade en el carro con los datos seleccionados, Ahora si añado otra vez el mismo producto con el mismo color y la misma talla este aumenta la cantidad del producto. Hasta aquí se está trabajando muy bien.

Los valores los obtengo mediante sessiones en:
**updatecart.php**

la cual es redireccionado al carrito **cart.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";

    //SESSION Guardo el dato seleccionado del color del producto.
    $_SESSION['colors'][$itemId]=$_POST['colors'];
    //SESSION Guardo el dato seleccionado de la talla del producto.
    $_SESSION['size'][$itemId]=$_POST['size'];

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and isset($_POST['qtyupdate'])) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['qtyupdate']); $i++) {
            $key = $_POST['arr_key_' . $i];
            $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_POST['qtyupdate'][$i];
        }

    } else {
        $qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;
        if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
            $_SESSION['qty'][] = array();
        }
        if (in_array($itemId, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
            $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $_SESSION['qty'][$key] + $qty;
        } else {
            array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $itemId);
            $key = array_search($itemId, $_SESSION['cart']);
            $_SESSION['qty'][$key] = $qty;
        }
    }
    header('location:cart.php');
    ?>
```

Y obtengo todos los datos en el carrito de la compra
**cart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$itemCount = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? count($_SESSION['cart']) : 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['qty'])){
    $meQty = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['qty'] as $meItem){
        $meQty = $meQty + $meItem;
    }
}else{
    $meQty = 0;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) and $itemCount > 0){
    $itemIds = "";
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $itemId){
        $itemIds = $itemIds . $itemId . ",";
    }
    $inputItems = rtrim($itemIds, ",");
    $meSql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id in ({$inputItems})";
    $meQuery = mysqli_query($kcon, $meSql);
    $meCount = mysqli_num_rows($meQuery);
}else{
    $meCount = 0;
}

if ($meCount == 0){
    echo "<div>No items in the basket</div>";
}else{
?>

<form action="updatecart.php" method="post" name="fromupdate">            
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>Producto</td>
<td>Precio</td>
<td>Cantidad</td>
<td>Total</td>
</tr>
<?php
$total_price = 0;
$num = 0;
while ($meResult = mysqli_fetch_assoc($meQuery)){
    $key = array_search($meResult['id'], $_SESSION['cart']);
    $total_price = $total_price + ($meResult['price'] * $_SESSION['qty'][$key]);
    $intemId=$meResult['id'];
    //SESSION obtengo el color
    $color = $_SESSION['colors'][$intemId];
    //SESSION obtengo la talla
    $size = $_SESSION['size'][$intemId];
}
?>
<tr>
<td class="cart-image">
<h3><?php echo $meResult['product']; ?>
//Muestro el color seleccionado
<?php echo $color; ?>
//Muestro la talla seleccionada
<?php echo $size?></h3>
</td>
<td class="cart-price"><?php echo $meResult['price']; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="qtyupdate[<?php echo $num; ?>]"
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['qty'][$key]; ?>"
autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
<input type="hidden" name="arr_key_<?php echo $num; ?>" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
<a href="removecart.php?itemId=<?php echo $meResult['id']; ?>" role="button">Eliminar</a>
</td>
<td>$<?php echo number_format(($meResult['price'] * $_SESSION['qty'][$key]),2); ?></td>
<?php
$num++;
}
?>                                    
</tr>
</table>
```

Ahora mi único problema es cuando selecciono el mismo producto pero con un color y talla diferente sólo actualiza los datos. Lo ideal sería conseguir duplicar el producto en una nueva fila como si fueran dos productos cuando se selecciona un color y talla diferente  del mismo producto.

cómo puedo conseguir obtener una nueva fila del mismo producto mediante la adición de un color diferente, o una talla diferente.

**Ejemplo**

### Producto | Precio  | Cantidad  |  Total

Camisa ---> $30.00 --->  1   ---> $30.00

color azul

Talla M

---

Camisa ---> $30.00 --->  1   ---> $30.00

color blaco

Talla L

---

Camisa ---> $30.00 --->  1   ---> $30.00

color negro

Talla XL

---

Camisa ---> $30.00 --->  1   ---> $30.00

color negro

Talla M

---

multiplicar el mismo producto cuando se seleccione un color o una talla diferente.

Comment: La forma más sencilla en mi opinión sería tener SKUs (o Ids) distintos para cada artículo, de lo contrario tendrías que replantear un poco como estás manejando el almacenamiento en la sesión. Asumo que esta diferenciación también debe verse en las facturas, correos transaccionales y en la cuenta del usuario?

Comment: @Shaz los productos tienen su id unico es decir tienen su id distintos para cada producto yo creo que para lograr obtener lo datellado es la sessión el updatecart.php mediante if y else pero no se como crear un no comprendo muy bien los parametros pero en fin pienso que las modifocaciones se deben basar en las sessión que esta en la pagina updatecart.php o también en el carrito de compras cart.php lo que quiero lograr es que al añadir el mismo producto pero  con un color diferente u talla este me muestre el mismo producto pero en una fila diferemte al añadir un valor diferente.

Comment: Si cada variante tuviera su id (o SKU) distinto como lo dices, considero que debería ser muy fácil manejar el array que almacenas en la sesión.

Comment: @Shaz no si me puedas ayudar con el tema amigo otro detalle que se debe tomar muy en cuenta es que al cambiar la cantidad de un producto duplicado es que no se vaya a perder el valor añadido. por otra parte creo para lograr esto esta en la sessiones espero me puedan ayudar con el tema ante mano muchas gracias Shaz.

Comment: @Shaz si amigo cada producto tiene su id unica lo que no contiene el producto en la misma la tabla es el color ni la talla. El color y la talla son llamado desde otra tabla en la base de datos que son mostrados los colores y la talla segun el id del producto.

Answer (score -3):

El problema es que solo usas el identificador de producto para verificar si es un nuevo producto o ya lo tenias, por tanto ignoras las variantes.

Para tenerlas en cuenta debes crear un identificador único que combine el id del producto, el color y la talla. De ese modo no se agruparan.

Por ejemplo puedes usar algo como:

```
$uniqueId = $itemId . '_' . $_POST['colors'] . '_' . $_POST['size'];
```

Esto deberías usarlo en updatecart.php en lugar de itemId para guardar los datos de colores y comprobar si debes aumentar las cantidades, etc.

---

El problema que tienes es que el código de cart.php depende de los itemId al haber usado arrays unidimensionales.

Ante esto la mejor solución que se me ocurre es refactorizar el código de udatecart.php y cart.php para no usar varias arrays enlazadas por itemId si no objetos o arrays multidimensionales. Por ejemplo, podriamos añadir una nueva linea con un código como el siguiente:

updatecart.php

```
$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : "";
$color = $_POST['colors'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$qty = isset($_POST['qty']) ? $_POST['qty'] : 1;

$uniqueId = $itemId . '_' . $color . '_' . $size;

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
   $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$uniqueId])) {
  //Estamos insertando un articulo nuevo
  $_SESSION['cart'][$uniqueId] = array(
      'itemId' => $itemId,
      'color' => $color,
      'size' => $size,
      'qty' => $qty
  );
} else {
  //Estamos actualizando un articulo
  $_SESSION['cart'][$uniqueId]['qty'] += $qty;    
}
```

De esa manera queda todo más claro y es más fácil operar. En cart.php puedes recorrer todo el array y obtener los distintos itemId o los datos que necesites.

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu repuesta, pero no me ejecuta ningún valor en el carrito de compras, me sale estos errores: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\cart.php on line 48`

`Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\cart.php on line 60`

Comment: si amigo el producto el color y la talla tienen su id unica 3 tablas distintas tablas producto la tabla color la tabla talla son llamado esto datos segun el producto ya que no todo producto tiene talla o color por ejemplo un accesorio. Podrias publicar el ejemplo completo con la modificación del updatecart.php y el cart.php ya que me muestra errores y no comprendo muy bie  el tema.

Comment: El error Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\cart.php on line 48 se refiere a que estas intentando usar un array como un string. Comprueba esa linea por si una variable que tu consideras un string puede haberse convertido en array.

Comment: El error  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyShop\cart.php on line 60 se trata de que el resultado de la consulta anterior te ha devuelto un booleano por lo que debe haber algun error con dicha consulta.

Comment: solucione los dos errrores pero ahora el problema biene desde updatecart.php no se encuentra la session key y si en esa session me muestra 7 errores.