# Crear un menú con estilo CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

He podido desarrollar un menú, funciona de esta manera al dar click en el enlace del menú, aparece, y al dar click en un espacio vació desaparece, hasta aquí, correctamente.

Pero tengo un pequeño inconveniente: Si vuelvo a dar click nuevamente en el mismo enlace, este no desaparece, entonces lo ideal sería que si doy click en el enlace del menú, aparezca. Esto funciona correctamente, pero si vuelvo dar nuevamente click en el mismo enlace, este no desaparece.

Quiero que desaparezca el menú al dar nuevamente click en el enlace de la misma manera como desaparece al dar click en un campo vacío. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este pequeño inconveniente?

Éste es mi código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu li a').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if ($('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').is (':hidden'))
      $('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').show();
    else
      $('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').hide();
    return false;
  });

  $('body,html').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
 background-color: #2C2C2C;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #222222);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
 min-height: 40px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 float:left;
 width:940px;
}
#menu ul {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
}
#menu ul li {
 float:left;
 position:relative;
 list-style:none;
}
#menu ul li a {
 color: #999999;
 float: none;
 line-height: 19px;
 padding: 9px 10px 11px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
}
#menu .dropdown-menu {
 display: none;
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top:35px;
 width:140px;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 border-radius:5px;
 border:1px solid #333333;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#menu .dropdown-menu:after {
 border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
 border-left: 6px solid transparent;
 border-right: 6px solid transparent;
 content: "";
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -6px;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 list-style:none;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
 clear: both;
 color: #333333;
 display: block;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 18px;
 padding: 3px 15px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color:#333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
 <li id="dropdown1"><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 12</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="dropdown2"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 21</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 22</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 32</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 42</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 52</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li id="dropdown3"><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 31</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 32</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 33</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El inconveniente está en cómo se esconden/muestran los submenús. Ahora mismo cuando se pulsa en un enlace el algoritmo (simplificado es el siguiente):

1. Cuando se haga click en un enlace dentro del menú
2. Esconde todos los submenús
3. Si el submenú está oculto, muéstralo
4. Si no, escóndelo
5. ....

Como todos los submenús se ocultan con `$('.dropdown-menu').hide();` (en el paso 1), cuando se llegue al condicional que comprueba si el submenú está oculto o visible, siempre se irá por la rama de que está oculto y por eso no funciona bien el menú.

Una solución rápida sería mover ese `$('.dropdown-menu').hide();` a ambas ramas del condicional, para entonces ya se habrá hecho la comprobación y ya no habrá problemas a la hora de esconder o mostrar submenús. Se repite una línea de código, pero tampoco es tan grave.

El código serí así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu li a').click(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if ($('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').is (':hidden')) {
      $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
      $('#'+parent+' .dropdown-menu').show();
    } else {
      $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('body,html').click(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#menu {
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #222222);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  float:left;
  width:940px;
}

#menu ul {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
}

#menu ul li {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  list-style:none;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: #999999;
  float: none;
  line-height: 19px;
  padding: 9px 10px 11px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#menu .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top:35px;
  width:140px;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:1px solid #333333;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#menu .dropdown-menu:after {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  list-style:none;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  clear: both;
  color: #333333;
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color:#333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li id="dropdown1"><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 12</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdown2"><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 32</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 42</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 52</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="dropdown3"><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 31</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 32</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 33</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo eres lo máximo amigo :) una pregunta amigo tienes conocimiento en php y mysqli tengo planteada una pregunta de como duplicar un producto en el carrito de compra si el usuario escoge el mismo producto pero con una talla o un color diferente estas es la pregunta [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16374/cómo-duplicar-un-artículo-en-la-cesta-en-una-nueva-fila-al-añadir-un-color-dife](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16374/cómo-duplicar-un-artículo-en-la-cesta-en-una-nueva-fila-al-añadir-un-color-dife) .

Comment: Gracias. Ahora miro la otra pregunta.

Comment: amigo tengo un nuevo problema con el mismo código plantee una nueva pregunta espero puedas mirarla [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18046/error-en-ejecutar-login-desplegable-con-jquery-similar-twitter](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18046/error-en-ejecutar-login-desplegable-con-jquery-similar-twitter)

Comment: Cuando fui a mirar la pregunta ya tenías un par de buenas respuestas :)

Comment: @J.Doe ¿Puedes explicar mejor en qué consiste la edición que has hecho? No comprendo "Derechos de copyright" y la respuesta deja de funcionar sin el código que eliminas

Comment: bueno realmente amigo no quiero causar polémicas debido a que estoy intentando similar una de las funciones de la librería de bootstrap y peor aun tomando el nombre de Facebook/Twitter para similar un menú idéntico, no quiero que se me bloquee la cuenta en esta sitio fantástico ya me ocurrió en otra cuenta ya no me permitieron publicar preguntas no me quedo más que cerrarla.